# C# date time not match sql date

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, winforms, ms-access

I try to develop a windows form program and I need to insert data. I need to insert today's date and time but when I try I get an error. I use access database. Where is my fault?

[image]

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand();
con.Open();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "insert into kayit (evraktarihi,evrakgelistarihi,gelissaati,geldigiyer,konusu,faturano,htfno,talepno,satınpersonel,teslimkisi,yapılanislem,acıklama,islemtarih) " +
    "values ('" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + "','" + DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "','" + textBox2.Text.ToString() + "','" + 
    textBox3.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox4.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox5.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox6.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox7.Text.ToString() + "','" + kullanici + "','" + 
     "','" + textBox8.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox1.Text.ToString() + "','" + dateTimePicker3.Value.ToShortDateString() + "')";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

I tried to change datetime.today to datetimepicker1.value but still doesn't work.

I can't find my error. I think this is a type unmatching error or sql syntax.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: The error tells you what the problem is (not enough parameters), also, research SQL Injection Attack (your code is very insecure).  I'm guessing that one of the text fields you are inserting contains a single quote (which is exactly why you should never create SQL commands the way you do it).

Comment: And add a tag for the dbms you're using. Your SQL is product specific.

Comment: ı did what did you want can you check?

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327).

Comment: Totally unrelated: When seeking help in an international forum like this, it is really beneficial to have variables, column names etc in english. It makes it a lot easier to read and understand what your are doing (or trying to do) because unless your native language english, there are going to be more people _not_ knowing _your_ language than people _knowing_ it.

Comment: What is the value of `cmd.CommandText` ?  If you step over that line then hover over it, copy that string to SQL server and run it, your will see your problem.

Comment: @Neil: _" I use access database"_ - from question. So, 'SQL Server' should be 'Access'.

Comment: Your problem is probably the use of `ToShortDateString` and/or `ToLongTimeString`: the resulting text is not in the same format expected by the database backend. Moreover, you should use query parameters: it would avoid the `ToShortDateString` and `ToLongTimeString` method calls and any other `ToString` calls (that, additionally, on `Text` properties are just useless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When requesting for help about an error, you should always include the error message and other relevant details.
Your error is probably inherent to wrong number of parameters or the format of some of them.

As already stated in my previous comment, the use of `ToString` after `Text` properties is useless: they are already `String` values.
More important, the use of `ToShortDateString` and similar methods are subject to globalization settings and what you get from such calls is probably incompatible with the format that the backend is expecting (different separators, different order of parts, etc.. ).

Looking in detail at your code, I found that the `values` clause contains an empty string before `textBox8.Text.ToString()`: it is split between line breaks, so hard to spot.
It is

> kullanici + "','" +
> "','" + textBox8.Text.ToString()

By the way, I here rewrite your code in a more readable (thus longer) form.
This provides several advatanges:

- The SQL command is shorter and more maintanable and readable.
- You don't need to convert to string every value and don't need to concatenate them.
- It does not suffer from SQL injection vulnerabilities.
- I included code to dispose resources properly (by means of `try/finally` and `using`).

However note that:

- The names of the parameters are totally arbitrary (they can also be @p1, @p2, etc..).
- The `OleDbType` types I specified are my best guess about your needs, maybe you have to change them.
- The actual values set for date and time parameters are also my best guess about what your intentions are.
- I would not mix SQL logic and UI access (but that's a totally different matter).

see [OleDbParameter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter) for explanation of query parameters.

```cs
con.Open();
try
{
    using var cmd = con.CreateCommand();

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@evraktarihi", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@evrakgelistarihi", OleDbType.DBTime).Value = DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@gelissaati", OleDbType.DBTime).Value = DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@geldigiyer", OleDbType.BSTR).Value = textBox2.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@konusu", OleDbType.BSTR).Value = textBox3.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@faturano", OleDbType.BSTR).Value = textBox4.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@htfno", OleDbType.BSTR).Value = textBox5.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@talepno", OleDbType.BSTR).Value = textBox6.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@satınpersonel", OleDbType.BSTR).Value = textBox7.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@teslimkisi", OleDbType.BSTR).Value = kullanici;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@yapılanislem", OleDbType.BSTR).Value = textBox8.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@acıklama", OleDbType.BSTR).Value = textBox1.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@islemtarih", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = dateTimePicker3.Value;

    cmd.CommandText = "insert into kayit"
      + "(evraktarihi,evrakgelistarihi,gelissaati,geldigiyer,konusu,faturano,htfno,talepno,satınpersonel,teslimkisi,yapılanislem,acıklama,islemtarih)"
      + "values"
      + "(@evraktarihi,@evrakgelistarihi,@gelissaati,@geldigiyer,@konusu,@faturano,@htfno,@talepno,@satınpersonel,@teslimkisi,@yapılanislem,@acıklama,@islemtarih)";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. It perfectly works. I am gonna rechange my all code like your code.